# Gitlab CI: Server in docker is asking for my SSH key passphrase, even though it doesn't have one

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, gitlab-ci-runner

Im trying to make Gitlab CI/CD work with some random repository to send all files to remote debian server. My before-script looks like that:

```
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
```

As you can see, I'm sending my test private key to debian server with public key in authorized_keys, but when I run job in pipeline, I get

```
$ which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 12
$ echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
Enter passphrase for (stdin): ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I already tried other keys, making sure I was just hitting return, I overrided passphrase in private key again, pressing return. All other results in SO are for /dev/fd/63, or are unresolved.

Comment: try to `chmod 600 authorized_keys` on debian server?

Comment: Already gave it 400, but I did 600 and still not resolved

Comment: did you copy `public key` for Jenkins User to `authorized_keys` debian server ?

Comment: Im not using Jenkins, but yes, I already added public key connected to this private key to ```authorized_keys``` on debian server. Private key is added to Variables in Gitlab.

Comment: Maybe I should also add that I'm using the private gitlab on another debian server.